# FCM getTopics not working - "attestStatus":"NOT_ROOTED"

Tags: cordova, firebase, push-notification, cordova-plugin-fcm

I am currently working and testing subscriptions for FCM topics.
I am trying to update the topic list that a user is subscribed for based on the user profile details.

In order to get the list of topics the user is already subscribed in, I am using this function which used to work just perfect for something like one hour of testings:

```
app.get("/getTopics", function(req, res, next) {

  var headers = {
    'User-Agent':       'Super Agent/0.0.1',
    'Authorization':    'key=my fcm key in here',
    'Content-Type':     'application/json'
  };

  // Configure the request
  let notifications_token = "the user notification token returned from the actuall app";
  var fcm_firebase = "https://iid.googleapis.com/iid/info/" + notifications_token + "?details=true";

  var options = {
    url: fcm_firebase,
    method: 'POST',
    headers: headers
  };

  // Start the request
  request(options, function (error, response, body) {
    if (body)
    {
      let body1 = JSON.parse(body);
      if (body1.rel)
      {
        let topics = [];
        for (let k in body1.rel.topics) {
          topics.push(k);
        }
        res.send(topics);
      }
      else res.send("Error");
    }
    if (error)
      res.send(error);
  });

});
```

As you can see, it was already working, and I received the topics that the user is subscribed for.
Suddenly, maybe due to many tests, I do not receive the topics, I receive

```
"attestStatus":"NOT_ROOTED"
```

instead.

I have tried to look in the Google docs about this, I was able to find this:

> attestStatus - returns ROOTED, NOT_ROOTED, or UNKNOWN to indicate
>   whether or not the device is rooted.

But there isnt anything describe what that means or how it should be solved.

How to solve this?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I have found the solution.

It happens when a token is unsubscribed from all of the topics, include the default: `android` and `ios` and `all`.

In such a case, we should consider that the token is valid but not rooted to any topic.

It is very important to **first verify** that there some subscriptions at all before trying to do actions with the token, unless we can receive an undefined error.

After re-subscribe to some topic, it returned to be working properly.